# python bitcoinrpc - unsure on how to pass parameters

Tags: python-3.x, bitcoin

Im trying to do the following call to bitcoin RPC and not surehow to pass the parameters in the correct way.

from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException

```
curl --user user:password -sf --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"check_btc_blockchain", "method": "listtransactions", "params":["slushpool", 10, 0, true] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332
```

Using  the following python code

```
# rpc_user and rpc_password are set in the bitcoin.conf file
rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332"%("user", "password"))


print(rpc_connection.listtransactions("slushpool", 10, 0, 0))
```

error: bitcoinrpc.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -1: JSON value is not a boolean as expected

I have tried using true and false also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this worked.

Setting the boolean value on a VAR.

```
trt = True
print(rpc_connection.listtransactions("slushpool", 10, 0, trt))
```